# Split row in many rows by number

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * FROM foo
```

returns me something like

```
name | price | value
foo  | 1     | 3
foo  | 2     | 2
```

I want receive:

```
name | price | value | record
foo  | 1     | 3     | row1
foo  | 1     | 3     | row2
foo  | 1     | 3     | row3
foo  | 2     | 2     | row1
foo  | 2     | 2     | row2
```

How I do this?

Comment: where does the column `record` come from and what does it mean?

Comment: What is your RDBMS?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and a solution for this problem will be highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 1):

OK, I tried to understand what you want, you just want to sort your rows by price and value, am I right? If so, just use `order by` clause as below:

```
select * from foo order by price, value;
```

OK, reEdit my answer as below, if you use PostgreSQL, things would be very simple.

```
select * from foo;
 name | price | value 
------+-------+-------
 foo  | 1 | 3
 foo  | 2 | 2
(2 rows)


select
    name,
    price,
    generate_series(1,value,1) as series_number
from
    foo;
 name | price | series_number 
------+-------+---------------
 foo  |     1 |             1
 foo  |     1 |             2
 foo  |     1 |             3
 foo  |     2 |             1
 foo  |     2 |             2
(5 rows)


select name,price,value from (
 select
     name,
     price,
     value,
     generate_series(1,value,1) as series_number
 from
     foo
) tmp order by price, value;
 name | price | value 
------+-------+-------
 foo  |     1 |     3
 foo  |     1 |     3
 foo  |     1 |     3
 foo  |     2 |     2
 foo  |     2 |     2
(5 rows)
```

And the way of mysql to finish this seems much more complex, see here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75785/how-to-generate-a-sequence-in-mysql

Comment: No friend, I need split the values. I don't have this five records, I have those twos and I need split in five according with the value total.

Comment: OK, I got, so what database do you use now ?

Comment: You just want to construct a series of number ended by value for each price, right?

Comment: I can use anyone

Comment: Right @shamn.x!

Comment: Please tell me what database are you using now, since there are many differences between different databases, so the way to implement this requirement maybe very different too.

Comment: anyone, mysql can be

Comment: And I see the question you edit now, the value is now same for each price? not a series of number ?

Comment: ITs not important, whatever actually

Comment: OK, I gave you an simple answer by PostgreSQL as above.

Comment: I have reEdited my answer, hope it helps.